# How to use Multimap as I need the output form?

Tags: java

How I can use `Multimap` using `java` which which each time print different value of each key. Example:

```
L has values  000,001,10
I has values   101, 100,00
```

I need  the output as follow:
ALI
first row contains first value of each key `001 000 101` second row contains second value of each key `110 001 100` third row contains third value of each key `11 10  00`

This code part:

```
public static   Multimap<String, String> Reading() throws IOException {

      Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("BBBB.txt");
        InputStreamReader fr = new InputStreamReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] columns= line.split(" ");


                 myMultimap.put(columns[1],columns[0]);


            }
```

The output shows each key with values

```
Ali 
[011,110 ,11][ 000,001,10][101, 100,00]
```

Comment: Ok, so you need to read a certain element of the list associated with each key? What did you try so far? Hint: try using `ListMultimap` instead of `Multimap` to make things easier.

Comment: thank you for you  i need to gets the different values each once  e.g. Ali 001 100 010      Ali 100 111 110        which each time different value for each letter

Comment: That's what you've described. So what's the problem doing it? You have a _list_ of values per letter after all (hint: you can get specific elements out of a list).

Answer (score 0):

You should realize you'll have to keep a *state* with your data: for each key, the data structure must remember where it stands in the iteration of the values.

Therefore you must expand the Map contract. Therefor you must èxtend`the`Map` functionality.

I propose the following (re-uses HashMap and List as a Wrapper class):

```
package samplingmultimap;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class SamplingMultiMap<K,V> implements Map<K, V>{

    private final Map<K, SamplingEntry> contents = new HashMap<>();

    /** Internal class holds data and keeps a cursor */
    private class SamplingEntry {

        private final List<V> data = new ArrayList<>();
        private int cursor;

        public void add(V value){
            data.add(value);
        }

        public V getNextData() {
            if(cursor < data.size()){
                return data.get(cursor++); // increment the cursor
            } else {
                return null; // You may want to re-browse the list, if so do cursor = 0 and return the first result
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        contents.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return contents.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        for(SamplingEntry entry: contents.values()){
            if(entry.data.contains(value)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        Set<Entry<K, V>> set = new HashSet<>();
        for(Entry<K, SamplingEntry> samplingEntry: contents.entrySet()){
            for(V value : samplingEntry.getValue().data){
                Entry<K, V> singleEntry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, V>(samplingEntry.getKey(), value);
                set.add(singleEntry );
            }
        }
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        SamplingEntry entry = contents.get(key);
        if(entry != null){
            return entry.getNextData();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return contents.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return contents.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        SamplingEntry existingEntry = contents.get(key);
        if(existingEntry == null){
            existingEntry = new SamplingEntry();
            contents.put(key, existingEntry);
        }
        existingEntry.add(value);
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for(Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e: m.entrySet()){
            put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        SamplingEntry oldValue = contents.remove(key);
        if(oldValue != null){
            return oldValue.getNextData();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int total = 0;
        for(SamplingEntry v:contents.values()){
            total += v.data.size();
        }
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        List<V> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(SamplingEntry v:contents.values()){
            result.addAll(v.data);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Example usage for your inputs:

```
public static void main(String[] argc){
    // Create and populate the Map
    SamplingMultiMap<String, String> map = new SamplingMultiMap<>();
    map.put("A", "011");
    map.put("A", "110");
    map.put("A", "11");
    map.put("L", "000");
    map.put("L", "001");
    map.put("L", "10");
    map.put("I", "101");
    map.put("I", "100");
    map.put("I", "00");

    // Get elements one by one
    System.out.println(map.get("A")); // returns 011
    System.out.println(map.get("A")); // returns 110
    System.out.println(map.get("A")); // returns 11
    System.out.println(map.get("A")); // returns null (but you may wish to rewind?)
    // Order of access is unimportant, state is confined to the Key
    System.out.println(map.get("L")); // returns 000
    System.out.println(map.get("I")); // returns 101
    System.out.println(map.get("L")); // returns 001
    System.out.println(map.get("I")); // returns 100
    System.out.println(map.get("I")); // returns 00
    System.out.println(map.get("L")); // returns 10
}
```

---

**Edit:** To answer how to completely decode a String into a list of symbols, just extends the Mapp further like so:

```
public class MultiDecoder extends SamplingMultiMap<Character, String> {
    public List<String> decode(String toDecode) {
        return toDecode.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).map(c -> get(c)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This decoder is used like this (remeber it inherits SamplingMultiMap so t has to be populated with the encoding entries):

```
public static void main(String[] argc) {
    // Create and populate the decoder with all the encodings
    MultiDecoder decoder = new MultiDecoder();
    decoder.put('A', "011");
    decoder.put('A', "110");
    decoder.put('A', "11");
    decoder.put('L', "000");
    decoder.put('L', "001");
    decoder.put('L', "10");
    decoder.put('I', "101");
    decoder.put('I', "100"); // Only 2 entries for 'I'

    // Decode an entire String:
    System.out.println(decoder.decode("ALI")); // returns ["011", "000", "101"]
    System.out.println(decoder.decode("ALI")); // returns ["110", "001", "100"]
    System.out.println(decoder.decode("ALI")); // returns [ "11",  "10", "101"] // the 'I' encoding loops around independently
    System.out.println(decoder.decode("ALI")); // returns ["011", "110", "100"] // The 'A' and 'L' encodings loop now also around
}
```

Comment: thankx for you, but i need to print the name as whole,,  multi times, each time with different encod for each character

Comment: You're gonna have to be much more explicit. I guessed what I could, but I have no idea what encoding you're talking about. Could you take the time to sit down, and provide a better explanation *and* a complete example, like a list of inputs and their associeted expected output? If you want a better answer you'll need to provide a better question.

Comment: ok my brother >>>>>>>>> i was doing encoding for the letters in dictionaryfor example,  a 1101
a 1001
a 1100
b 10010
b 11010
c 11110
c 10000 ,  just read sentences from file and gets it encoding >>> example (abc)...1101 10010 1110 and next gets second encoding for each letter>>>(abc) 1101 11010 1000 and so on are you understanded me ?

Comment: I think I do. Do you have the *guarantee* that there is a constant number of values per keys? Like in your examples, that there are *always* 3 encoding for every character ?

Comment: thank you so much to reply ...... not always some character more than 3  encoding just i gave that as example

Comment: Ok but can we mix encodings ? like `ALI=[011, 10, 100]` is fine?

Comment: Ok No problem my broth

Comment: Updated. I think it does what you want know. This decodes characters, and every time it decodes one, it will use an alternate encoding for it next time it is encountered.